# Violin plot using sequential rows as the Y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, violin-plot

I am trying to build a violin plot of the following data(CSV):

```
,Exp No.,Sensory accuracy(mm),Volume of Data points,Exp 1,Exp 2,Exp 3,Exp 4,Exp 5,Exp 6,Exp 7,Exp 8,Exp 9,Exp 10,Coefficient ,PPIP
0,1,10,3,9948,9998,9961,10042,10049,10029,9975,10020,9986,10002,34.07508050043479,0.4231902824036948
1,2,10,5,10012,10021,9991,10013,9993,10010,9995,9992,10007,10008,10.591401124392268,0.7024168537963643
2,3,10,7,10015,10002,9999,10013,10013,9995,10005,10007,10003,10016,7.223418704310154,0.7758332605676019
3,4,10,10,10019,10006,10006,10013,9995,10007,9996,10014,10002,10004,7.627435858647242,0.766226316659029
4,5,10,15,10010,10012,10014,10010,10014,10018,10006,10006,10009,10010,3.7252889522529364,0.8703132644393902
5,6,15,3,9972,10041,9953,10049,10005,9968,9978,10016,10054,10011,36.0248371112055,0.40966926227828393
```

Can perhaps be seen easier in the image

[image: Data set image]

The X axis is represented 'sensor accuracy' and 'volume of data points' column.

I want to find a way for the Y axis to be represented by the data from Exp 1-10, for each of the X-parameters.

Is there an easy way to do this without reformatting the table into individual experiment lines?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add your data as text and not as an image? Your changes of getting an answer are much higher because people can copy&paste your code.

Comment: In fact, it is not clear (at least to me) the expected output you want to achieve. Could you please show us an example (even an image) of what you are going to get? Moreover, what are *X-parameters*?

Comment: I have had ago, your question wasn't clear. Please review and make clarifications to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is ambiguous. I will try my best;

Data

[image]

Apply [df.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to  unpivot the df from wide format to long format and acquire the columns needed to plot violin plot

```
df2=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Sensory','volume'], value_vars=['Exp1', 'Exp2', 'Exp3', 'Exp4', 'Exp5', 'Exp6', 'Exp7', 'Exp8', 'Exp9', 'Exp10'])
```

Result

[image]

Plot Violin.

Violin takes three variables `x=variable 1, y=variable 2` and `hue=variable 3` where by `variable 3` can be used to classify'group by `split=True` if it has two distinct elements

You were not too definite. I plotted it as below. We can improve if needed.

Ungrouped:

```
ax = sns.violinplot(x="variable", y="value", hue="Sensory", data=df2, palette="muted")
```

If you need it grouped by `Sensory` then:

```
ax = sns.violinplot(x="variable", y="value", hue="Sensory", split=True, data=df2, palette="muted")
```